# I want to be able to mark dates between a start date and end date on my calendar in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Question is I have a rails application that is using a calendar helper to plot leave_start and leave_end on my calendar. I want to be able to mark the dates in between Ive tried a few things and so far no luck I was however able to get the leave_start and leave_end to show up but, so far not able to mark dates in between. Any help would be very much appreciated!!!!

Here is what I tried so far.

This is my entry controller...

```
class EntryController < ApplicationController


def index
   entry_by_start_date = Entry.where("emp_id = ?", 'BILL').group_by {|i| i.leave_start.to_date
   entry_by_end_date = Entry.where("emp_id = ?", 'BILL').group_by {|i| i.leave_end.to_date
   @entry_by_date = entry_by_start_date.merge(entry_by_end_date) {|key, oldval, newval| newval }

   ####^ this works but will only plot leave_start and leave_end on my calendar.

   # this is how I tried to plot all the dates between 
   ## leave_start and leave_end to be plotted on my calendar as well

   e_by_s = Entry.where("emp_id = ?", 'BILL').pluck(:leave_start)
   e_by_e = Entry.where("emp_id = ?", 'BILL').pluck(:leave_end)
   r_j = e_by_s.to_s
   r_g = e_by_e.to_s
   p_g = r_j.to_date
   t_g = r_g.to_date
   days_between = p_g.upto(t_g) { |date| puts date }
   @entry_by_all_dates = days_between.merge(days_between) {|key, oldval, newval| newval }
   @date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # index.html.haml
     format.json { render :json => @entry }
   end
 end
```

So for example:
 my leave_start date would be 2015-05-25

my leave_end date would be 2015-05-29

the days between both dates would be this

leave_start  2015-05-25

2015-05-26
2015-05-27
2015-05-28

leave_end 2015-05-29

Extra information

here is my calendar helper

```
 module CalendarHelper
   def calendar(date = Date.today, &block)
     Calendar.new(self, date, block).table
   end

   class Calendar < Struct.new(:view, :date, :callback)
     HEADER = %w[Sun Mon Tues Wed Thur Fri Sat]
     START_DAY = :sunday

     delegate :content_tag, to: :view

     def table
       content_tag :table, class: "calendar" do
         header + week_rows
     end
   end

   def header
     content_tag :tr do
      HEADER.map { |day| content_tag :th, day }.join.html_safe
   end
 end

 def week_rows
   weeks.map do |week|
     content_tag :tr do
       week.map { |day| day_cell(day) }.join.html_safe
    end
  end.join.html_safe
end

def day_cell(day)
  content_tag :td, view.capture(day, &callback), class: day_classes(day)
end

def day_classes(day)
  classes = []
  classes << "today" if day == Date.today
  classes << "notmonth" if day.month != date.month
  classes.empty? ? nil : classes.join(" ")
end

def weeks
  first = date.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week(START_DAY)
  last = date.end_of_month.end_of_week(START_DAY)
  (first..last).to_a.in_groups_of(7)
end
```

Also here is my view for my calendar

```
 #entry
   %h2#month
     = link_to "<", date: @date.prev_month
     = @date.strftime("%B %Y")
     = link_to ">", date: @date.next_month
   = calendar @date do |date|
     = date.day
     - if @entry_by_date[date]
       %ul
         - @entry_by_date[date].each do |entry|
           %li
             %span.u= entry.emp_id
           %ul
             %span.u= entry.leave_start.strftime('%m/%d')
             %span.u --
             %span.u= entry.leave_end.strftime('%m/%d')
     -elsif @entry_by_all_dates
       %ul
         - @entry_by_all_dates[date].each do |t|
           %li
             %span.u= t.emp_id
           %ul
             %span.u= t.leave_start.strftime('%m/%d')
             %span.u --
             %span.u= t.leave_end.strftime('%m/%d')
```

Update---

Tried this

```
    e_by_s = Entry.where("emp_id = ?", 'BILL').pluck(:leave_start).first
    e_by_e = Entry.where("emp_id = ?", 'BILL').pluck(:leave_end).first
    r_j = e_by_s.to_s
    r_g = e_by_e.to_s
    p_g = r_j.to_date
    t_g = r_g.to_date
    @days_between = p_g..t_g
    @entry_by_all_dates = (@days_between).map(&:to_s)
    @date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.haml
      format.json { render :json => @entry }
    end
  end
```

and in my view

```
 #entry
   %h2#month
     = link_to "<", date: @date.prev_month
     = @date.strftime("%B %Y")
     = link_to ">", date: @date.next_month
   = calendar @date do |date|
      = date.day
      - if @entry_by_date[date]
        %ul
          - @entry_by_date[date].each do |entry|
            %li
              %span.u= entry.emp_id
            %ul
              %span.u Type --
              %span.u= entry.indirect_id
            %ul
              %span.u= entry.leave_start.strftime('%m/%d')
              %span.u --
              %span.u= entry.leave_end.strftime('%m/%d')
            %ul
              %span.u Shift --
              %span.u= entry.am_pm
          - @entry_by_all_dates[date].each do |t|
            %li
              %span.u= t.emp_id
            %ul
              %span.u= t.leave_start.strftime('%m/%d')
              %span.u --
              %span.u= t.leave_end.strftime('%m/%d')
```

For some odd reason I get this error...

```
     ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert Date into Integer):
```

I attached a screen shot of my calendar it shows the start and end dates I want the dates between to show up as well.

[image: My calendar]

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date'

start_date  = Date.parse('2015-05-25')
end_date    = Date.parse('2015-05-29')
date_range  = start_date..end_date
(date_range).map(&:to_s)
```

This will output an array of Date range between (start_date..end_date) like this

Example:

```
["2015-05-25", "2015-05-26", "2015-05-27", "2015-05-28", "2015-05-29"]
```

Comment: Thats helps get the dates I want but I get this error for my view ....can't convert Date into Integer

Comment: Why do you want to convert Date into integer?

Comment: That's the error I got from trying your answer. @Akshay Borade

Comment: Try this   `your_date.strftime('%Q').to_i`  might be posible your view want date in millisecond. `date.strftime('%s').to_i` for seconds.

Comment: I updated my question with your suggestion to show the error I am receiving. @Akshay Borade

Comment: Also I added a screen shot of my calendar to better describe what I am trying to accomplish @Akshay Borade